# TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' Python3.9 image classification using tensorflow and keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I try this sample code for image classification

```
def show_classify_button(file_path):
    classify_btn = Button(top, text="Classify Image", command=lambda: classify(file_path), padx=10, pady=5)
    classify_btn.configure(background="#364156", foreground="white", font=('arial',10,'bold'))
    classify_btn.place(relx=0.79,rely=0.46)

def classify(file_path):
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((32,32))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    pred = model.predict([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#011638')
```

the terminal pop this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  line 39, in <lambda>
    classify_btn = Button(top, text="Classify Image", command=lambda: classify(file_path), padx=10, pady=5)
  line 49, in classify
    sign = classes[pred]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I try to check the data from the pred with output

```
[30990.06  46435.57  17636.973 16334.658 15860.342 16765.371 26879.748
 14579.97  41989.523 34359.215]
```

im not sure why because the data is from set of an array

im new with this and im using python3.9 can someone help me

Comment: there is no python 2.9 maybe you mean 3.9?

Comment: yea my bad sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to access classes variable on line 49

```
sign = classes[pred]
```

classes is of type `numpy.ndarray`.
So you're trying to access an array at index `pred` but because `pred` is not an number it's raising a `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` error.

You're treating classes like a dictionary by accessing it's values with a key and not with an index.